# Jenkins execute local Pipeline Script without SCM

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created this account because I couldn't find a solution for my problem. I hope you can help me. The goal is to write a local pipeline script for jenkins and use it in my pipeline (I'm using version 2.138). I don't want to write it in the jenkins UI or use any SCM (no git!). I saw that I can execute a shell scipt in a freestyle-job, but it doesn't work with pipelines. Maybe there is some plugin that can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you want to execute a shell script in a pipeline that's super easy use the sh step.  If you want to execute groovy code within a pipeline you can do that too with the load method (google pipeline load).

Comment: Thank you very much @RichDuncan, I didn't think it would be that easy